# NZ-SQL Select Last Day of current Year

Tags: sql, netezza

All.

Trying to find a way to find the last day of the current year, in Netezza SQL. 
For T-SQL I used `SELECT DATEADD(MS,-3,DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,0,GETDATE() )+1, 0))` but am having a brain fart in making one for NZ-SQL

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in Postgres, so I suspect it should also work in Netezza:

```
select current_date - extract(doy from current_date) * interval '1 day' + interval '1 year'
```

The idea is to subtract the current day-of-the-year from the current date.  This gives you the last day of the previous year.  Then add a one year interval.

EDIT:

Here is the same idea, but a different implementation:

```
select add_months(current_date - extract(doy from current_date), 12)
```

Or, in desperation

```
select to_date(cast(extract(year from current_date)*100000 + 1231) as varchar(255)), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

EDIT II:

By the way, in SQL Server, you can use this expression:

```
select dateadd(year, 1, cast(datename(year, getdate()) as datetime) - 1)
```

When you cast a string that looks like a year to a date/time, you get the first day of the year.

Comment: Unfortunatly, when I run your code I get this: ERROR [42S22] ERROR:  Attribute 'INTERVAL' not found

Comment: This did the trick: select add_months(current_date - extract(doy from current_date), 12) Thank you!!! Probably just Friday night that has my brain stuck. Will try to figure out the rest later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

And one more, using date_trunc, just for good measure.

select date_trunc('year',current_date) + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day';

Comment: THANK YOU! This helped me solve another problem (last day of the previous month using a -3 millisecnds)